# Windows mobile, how to get ID and Serial?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how I can get the Serial number and the ID number from Windows mobile ?

I need it in C#

thank's

Comment: ID and serial number of what?  Windows?

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to get a device's actual serial number programmatically.  There's no standard API for it, and I've seen very few that even had proprietary calls for it.

To get the device's unique ID, you're probably going to want to P/Invoke [GetDeviceUniqueID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908781.aspx) which is in the [Get Device ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158773.aspx) Sample in the SDK and was [ported to C# by the WinMo team](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2006/01/09/510997.aspx).